# The error about baxter simulator installation

Tags: ros, simulation, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying install the baxter smulitor according to http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation,but when
I  do this step "git clone git@github.com:RethinkRobotics/baxter_simulator.git" ,I got an error like this "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" please explain the reason and solution.thank you very much !!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195360/the-error-about-baxter-simulator-installation/) by [liyachao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20523/liyachao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-10-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Baxter` simulator is only available to the robot owners who have an access to the serial number (see http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Simulator_Installation):

```
Request access to the simulator repository by emailing RSDK.support@rethinkrobotics.com with your organization name and Baxter serial number and your github.com username.
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liyachao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20523/liyachao/) on 2014-10-20**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [liyachao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20523/liyachao/) on 2014-10-20**:
By the way,can I install RSDK and use the gazebo simulator without owning a Research robot?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-10-20**:
For that you should contact the customer support at Rethink. And if you found an answer helpful enough, mark the "check" sign so that others know the question is answered ;)